# Create multiple MVC folders in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering how flexible would rails be in changing the structure of the app directory.
So instead of having simply one **app** directory, I would like to have a **frontend** directory (with MVC) and an **admin** directory (with its own set of MVC).

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider using multiple MVC parts, you should look at [Rails Engines](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)

The basic idea is that you create a Core engine holding all your common codebase (models for example). Create 2 Rails application (frontend, backend) and mount the Core engine for both.

Each rails app can now have their own views,  controllers,  html/css. But they share the same logic through your engine.

Note that controllers, views and even html/css could be shared too (through engine) if need it. Routes also can be shared or separated.

To clarify:

- Frontend Rails application (mount Core Engine) (own git repo)
- Backend Rails application (mount Core Engine) (own git repo)
- Core Engine (own git repo, clone as git submodules in above rails applications)

Let's say tomorrow you want to add an API. Just create a new Rails application called `foo_api` and mount the Core Engine to add your buisiness logic. You will only need to configure your routes, views and controllers.

Comment: Interesting. So would my front-end and backend be separate rails apps? Or would the fit under a master rails app?

Comment: They would be 2 separate Rails application. However they could share the same database to begin with. This will add a huge amount of flexibility for your application.

Comment: Ok, since I am deploying to heroku, I can see it being a bit complicated to share the same database.

Also, how would the frontend and backend apps communicate with the core engine?

Comment: Sharing the same DB in heroku is simple, just use the same config file. The 2 apps communicate with the core engine just as usual Ruby classes (namespaced by the name of your engine). Instead of calling your model `User` it would be called by `Core::User.find(...)` for example.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. This is really enlightening! :) For the same DB, i would imagine the config file would have to point to a db on a different server? Normally when I host apps on heroku, it launches a vm with the db within it. So the only way I can think of sharing a db is by having it in its own VM outside heroku? Or is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34526/discussion-between-karan-and-pierre-louis-gottfrois)